# phantomjs highcharts > "Can't find variable: $"

Tags: jquery, highcharts, phantomjs

Hello my problem is this:

```
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():7 in loadScript
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():55
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():153
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():153
    ERROR: the options variable was not available, contains the infile an syntax error? see{ xAxis: { categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] }, series: [{ data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6,
148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] }] };
    Converted img name : D:/graph_.png
```

Why am I getting this error?
"Can't find variable: $"

In the highcharts-convert.js i change the config values to the correct path of the files.

```
    HIGHCHARTS: 'D:\highcharts.js',
    HIGHCHARTS_MORE: 'D:\highcharts-more.js',
    HIGHCHARTS_DATA: 'D:\data.js',
    JQUERY: 'D:\jquery.1.9.1.min.js',
```

I start this with php:

```
$type="Chart";

# Set file location.
$targetfile = "D:/test.js";

$prog = "D:/phantomjs.exe";
$progHc = "D:/highcharts-convert.js";
$callback = "D:/callback.js";

$outfile = "D:/graph_.png";

$result_flag = shell_exec( $prog . " " . $progHc . " -infile " . $targetfile . " -outfile " . $outfile . " -constr " . $type . " -callback " . $callback);
```

Comment: $ is a problem with jquery, so probably this module is not loaded properly.

Comment: Is this solved? Would love to know the solution if so.

Comment: having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in their documentation (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside) they tell to download `jQuery`, `highcharts.js`, `highcharts-convert.js`, and put it all in the same directory, and when you click in the jQuery URL they give, you download a file named `jquery.1.9.1.min.js`. Probably you did like me and just placed this file in the same place as the others. But if you look close, the config in `highcharts-conver.js` has the name of the jquery file with a dash instead of a dot before its version. So all you have to do is renate `jquery.1.9.1.min.js` to `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`.